# Currency Summarization Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to create a trigger that will summarize currency fields on custom object records (Property_Rate__c) and then input the sum into a lead field. Here is what I have. For clarification, each Property_Rate__c record is a calendar date, and each calendar date has an individual price. I would like to summarize these prices and then insert the sum into the lead field: Rate_Total__c.

Where am I going wrong?

```
trigger SummarizeRates on Lead (after insert, after update) 
{
    for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (l.Property__c != null && l.Arrival_Date__c != null && l.Departure_Date__c != null)
        {            
            String leadProperty = l.Property__c;
            Date arrivalDate = l.Arrival_Date__c;
            Date departureDate = l.Departure_Date__c;
            Decimal sum = 0.00;

            List<Property_Rate__c> rates = [SELECT Rate__c, Date__c, Property__c, Id FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Arrival_Date__c >= :arrivalDate AND Departure_Date__c < :departureDate AND Property__c = :leadProperty];

            for (Integer summarize : rates)
            {
                sum + Property_Rate__c.Rate__c;
            }

            l.Rate_Total__c = sum;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please dont do SOQL inside of for loops - you'll blow up governors; see various web pages on trigger bulkification; note also that after triggers require explicit DML to save results; before triggers will implicitly save results modified in Trigger.new

Comment: I will, but my priority for today is to get the summarization to work. Do you have any suggestions relating to that?

Comment: As crop1645 suggested, you have to avoid SOQL in FOR loop.  and your req is to sum all the property_Rate__c values??

Comment: you'll be hard pressed to find anyone on this forum - but I could be surprised - who would abide by SOQL inside of for loops

Comment: @AnithaJJ Yes I want to sum the property rates, and assign the sum to the lead.Rate_Total__c. How can I do this?

Comment: sum=sum+Property_Rate__c.Rate__C; may work. And try to modify your code by not using soql inside for loop.

Comment: @AnithaJJ Yes, I am getting the same error message: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you started....

A couple of things:

I do not know how big your data set would be for property rates but this will get you close. Also not sure about the calculations and how the relate to the lead or your data structure so pay close attention to the comparison of the dates in the calculation loop.

Also, I did not smoke test this so you will have to resolve any typos.

```
trigger SummarizeRates on Lead (before insert, before update) 
{

    Set<ID> propertyIDs = new Set<ID>(); //Properties in the leads
    Date minArrival; //Narrow by the earliest arrival date in the leads
    Date maxDeparture; //Narrow by the latest departure date in the leads

    for(Lead l : trigger.new){
        if (l.Property__c != null && l.Arrival_Date__c != null && l.Departure_Date__c != null)
            propertyIDs.add(l.Property__c); //Populate property ids

        //Set the min and max dates to attempts to narrow the scope of the SOQL
        if(minArrival == null || minArrival > l.Arrival_Date__c)
            minArrival = l.Arrival_Date__c

        if(maxDeparture == null | maxDeparture < l.Departure_Date__c)
            maxDeparture = l.Departure_Date__c;
    }


    Map<ID,Property_Rate__c[]> propertyRates = new Map<ID,Property_Rate__c>();

    //Get a list of rates mapped to the Property(s)
    for(Property_Rate__c pr : [Select Rate__c, Date__c, Arrival_Date__c, Departure_Date__c, property__c From Property_Rate__c Where ID IN :propertyIDs AND Arrival_Date__c >= :minArrival AND Departure_Date__c <= :maxDeparture]){
        if(propertyRates.containsKey(pr.Property__c))
            propertyRates.get(pr.Property__c).add(pr);
        else
            propertyRates.put(pr.Property__c,New Property_Rate__c[]{pr});
    }

    for (Lead l : Trigger.new)
    {
        if (l.Property__c != null && l.Arrival_Date__c != null && l.Departure_Date__c != null)
        {            
            Decimal sum = 0.00;

            for(Property_Rate__c pr : propertyRates.get(l.Property__c)){
                if(pr.Arrival_Date__c <= l.Arrival_Date__c && pr.Departure_Date__c > l.Departure_Date__c)
                    sum + pr.Rate__c;
            }

            l.Rate_Total__c = sum;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: n.b. as trigger is an after trigger (although not clear why OP has it this way), the `l.rate_total__c` will not be updated in the database without DML

Comment: the little thing..updated to before trigger